# How can i get the line of code per commit for a file in git

Tags: git

i tried using the below statement in git:

```
$ wc -l file name
```

Above statement gives me only for the latest version. But i need for each and every commit, so how can i get it?

Comment: To me, it's not clear what you're asking. Could you please update the question with more details and examples?

Comment: I think he need to get commit history of a specific line in specific file.

Comment: No . I need to get the total line of code per file for a particular commit.

Comment: `git show commithash:file/path | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

The command you posted has nothing in common with `git`. `wc` is a general purpose Unix tool that counts the bytes, characters, words or lines in a file (its name stands for `word count`). It cannot be used to count the number of lines of code, is it is language agnostic and cannot tell a line of code from a comment.

However, if you need the total number of lines in the file you can use the command:

```
git log --numstat --format=oneline -- file.txt | grep file.txt$
```

to get a history of changes on the specified file.

The output contains three columns separated by a variable number of spaces. The first column contains the number of lines added on each commit, the second column contains the number of lines removed on that commit, the third column is always the path of the file inside the project.

The commits are displayed in reverse order, as usual; the first line is the most recent commit that modified the file, the last line is the commit when the file was created (and should contain `0` on the second column).

It's easy to write a simple script (in your preferred scripting language) to parse the output and generate the number of lines of the file on each commit.

**Update**

The above command line doesn't preserve the commit hashes. Running only the `git log` part of it generates two lines for each commit. The first line contains the commit hash and the first line of the commit message, separated by a space. The second line is the one explained above. Still an easy job for a small parsing script.

In `bash`, the parsing script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then echo Cannot find the file \"$1\".; exit 1; fi

LINES=$(wc -l $1 | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]*\) .*$/\1/')
git log --numstat --format=oneline -- $1 | while read -r HASH COMMENT; do
  read -r INSERTED DELETED FILENAME
  echo $HASH $LINES
  LINES=$(($LINES-$INSERTED+$DELETED))
done
```

It accepts the file path as its first argument and produces a list of lines; each line contains the commit hash and the number of lines the input file had after that commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to get all of the commit hashes for a given `$filename` and check these out using a `for`-loop in your shell. For example (in Zsh):

```
git stash
for sha in $(git log --format=format:%H -- $filename); do
    git checkout $sha -- $filename
    echo "$(wc -l $filename) @ $sha" 
done
git stash pop
```

Comment: The script should verify if it's safe to `git checkout` before entering the loop. If the working copy contains not-committed changes it will probably fail. Also, there is no need to checkout the entire project.

Comment: @axiac: Indeed. This is a very simple example and not meant to be exhaustive. Nobody copies code from StackOverflow and pastes it straight into a terminal window, do they? ;)

Comment: When using the above code , the git checkout of a commit will alter the timestramp , author name of existing code for that commit. Can i use the same above statement without actually altering any commit history ?

Comment: @Benjamin: When using the code above no Git history will be altered. Each checkout will change only the copy of `$filename` in your working tree. You can checkout `origin/master` (or whichever HEAD) you like when you are done.